# How can I be notified of a banner notification in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, notifications, uikit

I'm writing an iOS application and I'd like to pause my app's motion content when the operating system decides to show a Banner Notification like this one:

[image: Banner Notification]

Is there a system `NSNotification` that I can observer or a method that gets called which I can react to? I've tried`applicationWillResignActive`, but that isn't called in this case.

Comment: Cheap shot: Does the window's frame or bounds change? If so, can you try KVO on the app window's bounds?

Comment: Short Answer: Nothing legal.  APNS was designed as a client-server model, so you should never be notified of a banner that isn't yours.  Long Answer: Notification banners appear, and so must either be views or layers.  Either way, I have a hunch that the window hierarchy probably changes when a banner gets shown.

Comment: @CodaFi- My guess though is the notification is not in *your* window and is wholly outside your app's view hierarchy.

Comment: The other thing I'd do if I had access to a dump of the iOS dmg would be to look for private frameworks, just to understand how it's done. I'd suggest emailing the springboard team to see if they can guide you.

Comment: @Moshe Why Springboard?

Comment: Springboard is the home screen. I suspect that it would be responsible to display the notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a stab at it this morning, and I'm inclined to say that there's no public API for this.

I tried using the code outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838753/what-is-the-cfnotificationcenter-callback-function-observer), and didn't catch any notifications. Then, I ran a bunch of "tests" to see if I could find anything.

To test, I created a pair of applications, [one to schedule notifications (GitHub link)](https://github.com/MosheBerman/notification-sender), and [one to try and "catch" them (GitHub link)](https://github.com/MosheBerman/notification-catcher). In my Sender app, I can send N notifications every N seconds. I picked some arbitrarily high value and sent them.

In my catcher, I've tried looking at visibleRect values up and down the layer hierarchy. (The keyWindow lives in a layer, but it's superview, and super layer.delegate are both nil) I haven't checked constraints, but that shouldn't matter. I've looked at the application's window, it's nil superview, it's layer, it's subviews. The application's bounds aren't effected either. The app is sandboxed so well, that springboard and notification center don't exist in the app's world.

I started going down the path of accessing private frameworks, but decided it wasn't worth the effort.

I've opened Instruments and looked at the transparency levels of the views. (Is it possible to force all views in a hierarchy to be opaque, and then use that to see if the banner is blocking something? Perhaps it's not "blocking" if it's transparent?)

I've also attempted to take a screenshot, and check the colors in the top area of the screen, but that wouldn't work because you need to pass a view in to the context. Even if it would work, it wouldn't be particularly performant.

Another thought I've had would be to listen for push notifications on the push port, but I doubt that Apple would allow you to catch another app's notifications. As a developer, I wouldn't send private info in an alert, but it's still a concern.

The truth is that notification banners don't really cause your application to become inactive, so I'm not sure that this behavior is wrong. If it's a convenience, file a bug. 
How about requesting `DeviceWillShowNotificationNotification`?